# C# Create a library that includes nuget dependencies for downstream projects

Tags: c#, nuget

Here's what I'm trying to do.

With Java, when I create a library or framework project with maven I can dictate its dependencies. Those dependencies are then transitively included in downstream projects that use my library as a dependency.

I'm having trouble replicating this with C# and nuget. I want to create a library project that wraps a number of various nuget dependencies. In my experimentations, my downstream projects aren't inheriting these transitive dependencies and I have to include them again in that solution's own nuget.

How can I have these dependencies wrapped or inherited in a manor like this? Is this even possible or is there a different paradigm for .net projects that I'm not aware of?

Comment: It should be doing it, unless you and I are using different definitions of "downstream". Can you update your question with a quick example of a hierarchy of 3 or 4 projects including the `.nuspec` xml for each?

Comment: This may be the root of my problems. In ProjectA, I have the output type set to Class Library. I build that project and generate ProjectA.dll. In ProjectB, I import ProjectA.dll and don't have access to any libraries that it uses. Is this not the correct methodology?